# Supporting browser back button in already developed ajax based web site

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, history.js, sammy.js

I have already developed ajax enabled web site. Most of the time we do partial rendering and use some templates to render content in the client side. The issue is now we need to support browser back button  .

I tried to use Sammy.js but it seems like we need to change every ajax calls and events to use sammy to keep the history with the client. Is there any other library like History.js or something else so that we can do it in easier or do in in a separate module without affecting all.

Answer (score 1):

To my limited knowledge on the subject, I don't think there is still a way to do this implicitly.

YUI seems to be doing it a little different than Sammy, check if that helps.

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/history/

http://yuiblog.com/sandbox/yui/3.2.0pr1/examples/history/history_tabview.html#tab=2

Comment: Thanks @Shiran ,I'll have a try on that .